# Building Go with Bazel could not resolve a repository

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

I am following the steps from "Building Go Services With Bazel" [youtube](https://youtu.be/v7EAdff-YXQ?t=2109) and created a simple project with dependency that fails to build with an error:

```
ERROR: /builds/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/cmd/BUILD.bazel:3:11: no such package '@com_github_pallinder_go_randomdata//': The repository '@com_github_pallinder_go_randomdata' could not be resolved and referenced by '//cmd:cmd_lib'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//cmd:cmd' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.263s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 165 targets configured)
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 165 targets configured)
```

[Whole log](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/jobs/1512867123)

### Versions

```
$ bazel --version
bazel 4.1.0

$ go version
go version go1.17 linux/amd64
```

### File structure

Project: https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go

- [cmd/](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/tree/main/cmd)

  - [BUILD.bazel](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/blob/main/cmd/BUILD.bazel)
  - [hello.go](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/blob/main/cmd/hello.go)
  - [hello_test.go](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/blob/main/cmd/hello_test.go)
- [BUILD](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/blob/main/BUILD)
- [WORKSPACE](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/blob/main/WORKSPACE)
- [go.mod](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/blob/main/go.mod)
- [go.sum](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/blob/main/go.mod)

### Steps

See [.gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml)

- `go mod init gitlab.com/mvfwd/issue-bazel-go`

  - creates `go.mod`
- `go mod tidy`

  - creates `go.sum`
- `bazel run //:gazelle`

  - creates `cmd/BUILD.bazel`
- `bazel build ...`

  - fails with error

Thought it might be because of the dash in "go-randomdata", so added another non-dashed dependency (github.com/stretchr/testify/assert), got the same issue.

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

**UPD**:
Solution was to use the following combination

```sh
$ bazel run //:gazelle
$ bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos -from_file=go.mod -to_macro=deps.bzl%go_dependencies
$ bazel run //:gazelle
```

As described [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#running-gazelle-with-bazel). `update-repos...` part would update WORKSPACE with all the necessary dependencies.

Comment: Figured out what was the problem.

(1) WORKSPACE was missing dependencies, that had to be added with `go_repository` rule, [doc](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle/blob/master/repository.rst#go_repository)

(2) Gazelle actually can resolve the dependency, but with updated command `$ bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos -from_file=go.mod`

Comment: Please answer your question so that it doesn't appear unnswered anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was to use the following combination

```sh
$ bazel run //:gazelle
$ bazel run //:gazelle -- update-repos -from_file=go.mod -to_macro=deps.bzl%go_dependencies
$ bazel run //:gazelle
```

As described [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#running-gazelle-with-bazel).

`update-repos...` part would update `WORKSPACE` file with all the necessary dependencies.